# while taking raw input in phycharm I am getting error

Tags: python

```
class Hangman():

    def __init__(self):
        print
        "Welcome to 'Hangman', are you ready to die?"
        print
        "(1)Yes, for I am already dead.\n(2)No, get me outta here!"
        user_choice_1 = raw_input("->")
```

At This line I am getting error do I have to import some library for this raw input

```
        if user_choice_1 == '1':
            print
            "Loading nooses, murderers, rapists, thiefs, lunatics..."
            self.start_game()
        elif user_choice_1 == '2':
            print
            "Bye bye now..."
            exit()
        else:
            print
            "I'm sorry, I'm hard of hearing, could you repeat that?"
            self.__init__()
```

Comment: What error are you getting, specifically?

Comment: In addition to including the error, why do you have `print` and the text on different lines? Testing this briefly, I just get empty lines printed and the strings are ignored. Use `#` to make comments, your code editing has gone wonky.

Comment: esses)
                print
                "Progress: " + self.progress_updater(guess, the_word, progress)
                print
                "Letter used: " + letters_used

Comment: File "E:/PycharmProjects/untitled1/hangman.py", line 49
    if guess in the_word and not in letters_used:
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I'm confused. `if guess in the_word and not in letters_used:` is in your error message, but nowhere in the code you've shown us so far.

Comment: @MustafainRehmani Please edit additional information into your original post and format it correctly.

Comment: ... Probably best to edit your question and get the formatting correct. That is illegible.

Comment: Yes this is the error i am having @kevin how to solve this ?

Comment: First, show us your whole code.

Comment: If you are using Python 3, there is no `raw_input`, just `input`.

Comment: @kevin how could i show to my code while posting my code here it says words out of limit ?

Comment: @Christian i am using phycharm

Comment: @MustafainRehmani PyCharm is an IDE, which has to use a python interpreter installed somewhere on your system. See e.g. `File->Settings->Project->Interpreter`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> File "E:/PycharmProjects/untitled1/hangman.py", line 49 
> if guess in the_word and not in letters_used:
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax 
> Process finished with exit code 1
> ```

This error indicates that the problem is not with your `raw_input` line, but rather with the code on line 49. `[something] and not in [something]` is not a valid expression. `not in` is a binary operator, so it requires two arguments, one on either side. You only gave it one on the right. Try:

```
if guess in the_word and guess not in letters_used:
```

Comment: yes its removed now same error on this line    elif guess not in the_word and not ( in letters_used):